# Spring Boot Connecting to 2 Different Data Sources Using application.properties or application.yaml File

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, db2

My application using Spring JPA and it should connect to 2 different data sources.  One to connect to DB2, the other to connect to Oracle.

I have set my application properties like below:

```
# DB2 DATA SOURCE
# ==============================
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:db2://server:port/database:currentSchema=schema-name;
spring.datasource.username=user1
spring.datasource.password=password1
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver

# ORACLE DATA SOURCE
# ==============================
oracle.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:port/database
oracle.datasource.username=user2
oracle.datasource.password=password2

# ==============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ==============================
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

# **How to specify the dialects hibernate needs to use in this scenario?**
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2390Dialect
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

Above, my DB2 is working fine but as soon as I add 2nd data source (for Oracle), I am getting

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set**

Answer (score 1):

Setting properties in `application.yml` or `application.properties` don't automatically create DB connections. When using multiple databases you have to configure them manually.

In your case, Spring configures db2 because of `spring.datasource.*` properties and ignores Oracle DB as it treats them as custom properties. To fix this, you have create separate configuration classes that defines

1. Data Source
2. Transaction Manager
3. Entity Manager Factory

Spring Data team created an example for this.

1. [Customer DB](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/main/jpa/multiple-datasources/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/multipleds/customer/CustomerConfig.java)
2. [Order DB](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/main/jpa/multiple-datasources/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/multipleds/order/OrderConfig.java)

Comment: Thank you for answering.  Following that and few other posts I have come up with a solution but still have problem.  The problem with the urls you provided is that they dont specify hibernate dialect anywhere for some reason.  That is exactly problem with my solution since I have 2 different database vendors (DB2 and Oracle).  I posted SO here, would you mind taking a look?  Much appreciated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72296481/spring-boot-hibernate-error-access-to-dialectresolutioninfo-cannot-be-null-when